# labelling chunks of data after finding indices

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing

I would like to find certain indices of a variable called "heading".  I want to find the indices referring to the value in "heading" between 0 and 20, 20 and 40, 40 and 60, etc.  I then want to extract other variables depending on these indices, such as speed.  I have written this, but I guess is inefficient, so would like to but it into some kind of loop or indexing algorithm.

```
heading_index1 = find(heading>0 & heading<=20);
heading_index2 = find(heading>20 & heading<=40);
heading_index3 = find(heading>40 & heading<=60);
```

etc

```
speed1 = speed(heading_index1);
speed2 = speed(heading_index2);
speed3 = speed(heading_index3);
```

etc

Comment: Are those logical expressions always of the same pattern? Then I would instead define the borders with something like `bins=[0:20:360]` and then loop thorough, using `heading>bins(x) & heading<=bins(x+1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is more efficient if you use logical-indexing directly (so no `find` command in between). If you want to automatize the whole thing, you can use a struct or cells:

```
% random vectors to create a minimum working example
heading = rand(100,1)*100;
speed = rand(size(heading));

% limit vector
lim = [0 20 40 60];

% declare storage structures
S = struct();
C = cell(1,length(lim)-1);

% loop through limits
for i = 1:length(lim)-1
    % logical vector
    lg = heading > lim(i) & heading <= lim(i+1);
    % index (its faster to use logical vectors for indexing than integers)
    chunk = speed(lg);

    % assign to struct
    fld = num2str(i,'F%d');
    S.(fld) = chunk;

    % assign to cell
    C{i} = chunk;
end
```

You can choose if you like the structure-way or the cell-way. It shouldn't make a difference in terms of memory space.

Personally, I prefer the struct as I can define names, which I can interpret but it is also a bit tedious to create the field name rather than just index a cell

Comment: Thanks max.  I'm using structures not cells.  There were 4 variables that I wanted to chunk in this fashion.  Then combine these into a 1X4 structure:

    speed_fld = num2str(i,'Chunk%d');
    Speed.(speed_fld) = speed_chunk;

etc

     combined = [TimeJ,Speed,Heading,Beta]; %to give 1X4 structure

I want to now name each of the 4 resulting rows in this 1X4 structure as: Time, Speed, Heading, Beta.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: `struct('Time',time_chunk,'Speed',speed_chunk,...)`